# Can't get mesh to deform properly with rig

Tags: mesh, rigging

I am rigging my model I made and I can't seem to get the part of the leg that connects to the butt to deform with the rig properly when bending the legs backwards or sideways. The rig deforms fairly well when bending the leg forward, However when bent backwards or to the side the rig looks much worse, I've been trying to figure out how to fix this issue to no avail, I've tried redoing topology and bone placement as well as redoing my weight paints, I've no clue how to fix this while keeping the effect of the abdomen moving up slightly as well as the butt moving with the thigh. [image: Legs of mesh bending forward making a smooth crease in the model]

[image: Crease between butt and thigh is very rigid and pointy as well as the crease between the spine and butt]

[image: Thigh of model overlaps the hip region when moving leg to the side]

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KspyBcJIGwpt4ghiJUQV0ZEJB45MUBoa/view) (Just Incase)

Comment: With automatic weights, it doesn't look bad to me, except when the leg is moved sidewards. To keep the volume in this pose you can add hip bones.

Comment: Just wanted to note that there are 1200 duplicated vertices. And anatomical I think the upper part of the body is too small and the arms are too short, aren't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved the results I was looking for after taking a break. I figured this out by changing the topology drastically to better indicate where the body would crease or rotate at, such as the groin area following into the hip more. As well as weight painting changes to nearby bones. Anatomical references also helped a ton to understand what bones cause what to move and how much, it's always helpful to have that on the side.